# Illegal expression when pattern matching with maps in Erlang

Tags: hashmap, erlang, records, erl

I'm trying to execute sample code on the interactive shell from Armstrong's Erlang book. This is what the book says is the case:

```
1> Henry8 = #{ class => king, born => 1491, died => 1547 }. #{ born => 
1491, class=> king, died => 1547 }.
2> #{ born => B } = Henry8.
#{ born => 1491, class=> king, died => 1547 }.
```

However, this is what I'm getting on the shell, it seems the pattern matching is failing:

```
1> Henry8 = #{ class => king, born => 1491, died => 1547 }.
#{born => 1491,class => king,died => 1547}
2> #{ born => B } = Henry8.
* 1: illegal pattern
```

Answer (score 3):

`=>` is for constructing a map. To pattern match a map, you need to use `:=` instead.

```
1> Henry8 = #{ class => king, born => 1491, died => 1547 }.
#{born => 1491,class => king,died => 1547}
2> #{ born := B } = Henry8.
#{born => 1491,class => king,died => 1547}
3> B.
1491
```

This is documented in the section "Maps in Patterns" [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id82477).

Answer (score 0):

The code example was preceded by the text:

> **Pattern Matching the Fields of a Map**
>   The `:=` syntax we used in a map literal can also be used as a map pattern.

And that text was preceded by a whole section explaining the differences between `=>` and `:=` when constructing a map, so you should have been aware of the two different syntaxes.

In the book, line 2 of the example says:

```
2> #{born := B} = Henry8.
```

yet in the shell you typed:

```
2> #{ born => B } = Henry8.
```

I suggest you reread `section 5.3` a little more carefully, and also read the [pertinent section of LYSE](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps), which includes this example:

> ```
> 1> Pets = #{"dog" => "winston", "fish" => "mrs.blub"}.
> #{"dog" => "winston","fish" => "mrs.blub"}
>
> 2> #{"fish" := CatName, "dog" := DogName} = Pets.
> #{"dog" => "winston","fish" => "mrs.blub"}
>
> 7> CatName.
> "mrs.blub"
>
> 8> DogName.
> "winston"
> ```
>
> Here it's possible to grab the contents of any number of items at a
>   time, regardless of order of keys. You'll note that elements are set
>   with `=>` and matched with `:=`. The `:=` operator can also be used to update an existing key in a map